# How to get selected TD (child) value

Tags: jquery, html

have some trouble here while getting the text value of my td while clicking my span.
It always alert the first row even if I click the span in my 2nd row.

Here's my code:

```
 $("#Item_Tbl").children("tr").children("td:last-child").children('span').each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    var itemId = $("#Item_Tbl_Body > tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").html()
                    alert(itemId)   
                });
            });
```

Comment: show your html code :)

Comment: Hi Cattla, already got it with the help of Sir Arun and Sir Paul. Anyway, Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the current `tr`, you are always selecting all the second `td` elements in the table so the getter version of [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html) will return the content of the first `td` in the called set.

`this` inside the click handler refer to the clicked `td` element so you can use that to find the clicked `tr` element using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) then you can find the 2nd td inside the current `tr` like

```
$("#Item_Tbl > tr > td:last-child > span").click(function () {
    var itemId = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:nth-child(2)").html()
    alert(itemId)
});
```

Also note how the selector was shortened.

Comment: This is really good. Thanks Sir Arun for your response, it helps me a lot! And noted, i will shortened my selectors next time!

Answer (score 0):

You're always asking for the full set of `td:nth-child(2)` elements in the table; `html()` will, by definition, give you the contents of the *first* in the list.

Ask, instead, for the row containing the clicked element:

```
$("#Item_Tbl > tr > td:last-child > span").each(function () {
   $(this).click(function () {
     var itemId = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:nth-child(2)").html()
     alert(itemId)   
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi Sir Paul! Thanks for the advice, Got it! Everything is noted.